# Spoofing an NTP server to allow bruteforce on any smartphone

Tags: passwords, brute-force, password-cracking, ntp

We all know that smartphones (i'll take iPhone as an example) rely on SNTP/NTP servers to update a device's time and date. So, by creating an SNTP server that mimics Apple's server, we can actually change a device's date and time over WIFI in order to bruteforce the passcode of the device without waiting the timeout period.

(By changing the device time over and over via WIFI)

**Isn't that possible?**

Comment: Also, I think the device gets its time from the cellular network, not NTP.

Comment: The device *does* get it's time from NTP.

Comment: I wonder if someone could port OpenNTPD to iOS. It can double check the time against `https://google.com`

Comment: You can [brick an iPhone using NTP however](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/04/14/ios_date_bug_can_be_exploited_over_wifi_using_ntp/).

Comment: That was before 9.3.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Answer:** No, a bruteforce attack would most likely fail.

http://www.payetteforward.com/my-iphone-is-disabled-connect-to-itunes-fix/

According to this site, and anyone who has ever been a mean big brother, there are only 10 times you can attempt to unlock an iPhone before it is completely locked and needs to be restored.

**1-5 failed attempts** - The phone will not lock.

**6 failed attempts** - The phone will lock for one minute.

**7 failed attempts** - The phone will lock for 5 minutes.

**8 failed attempts** - The phone will lock for 15 minutes.

**9 failed attempts** - The phone will lock for 60 minutes.

**10 failed attempts** - The phone will be disabled and will need to be restored.

So, as previously stated, 10 attempts will be your maximum. Also, Apple has released several new ways to set a passcode on your phone without having the use the 4 digit numeric code, which has a maximum of 10,000 passcodes (0000 - 9999). Users can use a 6 digit passcode which has a maximum of 1,000,000 possible codes (000000 - 999999), or even a phrase, which has a much greater number of possibilities for passwords.